# Making maps in go before anything

Tags: go, maps

I am following the go tour and something bothered me.

> Maps must be created with make (not new) before use

Fair enough:

```
map = make(map[int]Cats)
```

However the very next slide shows something different:

```
   var m = map[string]Vertex{
    "Bell Labs": Vertex{
        40.68433, -74.39967,
    },
    "Google": Vertex{
        37.42202, -122.08408,
    },
}
```

This slide shows how you can ignore `make` when creating maps

Why did the tour say maps have to be created with `make` before they can be used? Am I missing something here?

Comment: The wording of that is off, they mean you can't use new to create maps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the only reason to use make to create a map is to preallocate a specific number of values, just like with slices (except you can't set a cap on a map)

```
m := map[int]Cats{}
s := []Cats{}
//is the same as
m := make(map[int]Cats)
s := make([]Cats, 0, 0)
```

However if you know you will have a minimum of X amount of items in a map you can do something like:

```
m := make(map[int]Cats, 100)// this will speed things up initially
```

Also check http://dave.cheney.net/2014/08/17/go-has-both-make-and-new-functions-what-gives

Answer (score 1):

So they're actually right that you always need to use `make` before using a map. The reason it looks like they aren't in the example you gave is that the `make` call happens implicitly. So, for example, the following two are equivalent:

```
m := make(map[int]string)
m[0] = "zero"
m[1] = "one"
// Equivalent to:
m := map[int]string{
    0: "zero",
    1: "one",
}
```

#### Make vs New

Now, the reason to use `make` vs `new` is slightly more subtle. The reason is that `new` only allocates space for a variable of the given type, whereas `make` actually initializes it.

To give you a sense of this distinction, imagine we had a binary tree type like this:

```
type Tree struct {
    root *node
}

type node struct {
    val         int
    left, right *node
}
```

Now you can imagine that if we had a `Tree` which was allocated and initialized and had some values in it, and we made a copy of that `Tree` value, the two values would point to the same underlying data since they'd both have the same value for `root`.

So what would happen if we just created a new `Tree` without initializing it? Something like `t := new(Tree)` or `var t Tree`? Well, `t.root` would be nil, so if we made a copy of `t`, both variables would not point to the same underlying data, and so if we added some elements to the `Tree`, we'd end up with two totally separate `Trees`.

The same is true of maps and slices (and some others) in Go. When you make a copy of a slice variable or a map variable, both the old and the new variables refer to the same underlying data, just like an array in Java or C. Thus, if you just use `new`, and then make a copy and initialize the underlying data later, you'll have two totally separate data structures, which is usually not what you want.

Comment: You don't need to use make to create a map actually, `map[string]int{}` works exactly the same. Also new returns a pointer to the element's zero value and is equivlant to `&struct_name{}` or `i := uint64(0); iptr := &i` vs `iptr := new(uint64)`.

Comment: Yes - as I said in the answer, the literal notation is syntactic sugar for calling `make` and then populating the map explicitly.

Comment: You have answered my question however I don't really understand what you mean with the `make` and the `new`. I can understand that you want to use `new` when you want two separate objects because a copy of an object would still point to the same object however when would you want to use `make` then?

Comment: Ah, I think I wasn't clear. A map is in some ways itself a pointer. That is, a map variable is, under the hood, a struct with a few fields, and one of them is a pointer to a big chunk of memory to store the contents of the map in. Thus, if you have two copies of the same map, their pointers will point to the same memory (just like if you have two copies of the same slice). The reason you need to use `make` is that if you don't, that pointer will be nil, and so when you copy the map, you'll have two separate maps with nil pointers, and if you `make` one of those maps, it won't `make` the other.

Comment: When I was talking about `new`, I didn't mean to emphasize the fact that it returns a pointer; that's irrelevant. I could have just as easily said `var m map[int]string` instead of `m := new(map[int]string)`.

Comment: The fact that `new` returns a pointer (of type `*map[int]string` instead of just `map[int]string`) is irrelevant, and was probably pretty confusing. That wasn't what I meant to focus on.